# Why the HTML Text in Rich Content is showing image as 'Graphic'?

Tags: html, css

I am working on one project where I want to reassign a html text to a rich text control which is designed for web. This rich text control support html doc to display the record.

I am facing problem while uploading html with images as follows:

```
<font size=2 color="#000000" face="Arial">
<div>
<span style="font-size: 9pt; font-family: 'arial'; color: #000000;">Test Embedded Image </span>
<span style="font-size: 8pt; font-family: 'Arial'; color: #000000;">graphic</span>
</div>
<div>
<span style="font-size: 9pt; font-family: 'arial'; color: #000000;">Text after image sd</span>
<div><table width=538 border=1 cellpadding=0 bordercolor="#414141" cellspacing=0>
<tr valign=top>
<td width=180 valign=top><font size=2 color="#000000" face="Arial">
<div>
<span style="font-size: 9pt; font-family: 'arial'; color: #000000;">test </span>
</div>
</font>
</td>
<td width=178 valign=top><font size=2 color="#000000" face="Arial">
<div>
<img src="Image_1.PNG" width="166" height="238" border="0" alt="graphic"/>
</div>
</font>
</td>
<td width=178 valign=top><font size=2 color="#000000" face="Arial">
<div>
<img src="Image_2.PNG" width="166" height="238" border="0" alt="graphic"/>
</div>
</font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top>
<td width=180 valign=top><font size=2 color="#000000" face="Arial">
<div>
<img src="Image_3.PNG" width="166" height="238" border="0" alt="graphic"/>
</div>
</font>
</td>
<td width=178 valign=top><font size=2 color="#000000" face="Arial">
<div>
<span style="font-size: 8pt; font-family: 'Arial'; text-decoration: underline; color: #0066cc;"> xxx</span>
</div>
</font>
</td>
<td width=178 valign=top><font size=2 color="#000000" face="Arial">
<div>
<span style="font-size: 8pt; font-family: 'Arial'; text-decoration: underline; color: #0066cc;"> Web URL</span>
</div>
</font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

But the images are replaced with the `graphic` text as shown in fig.

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have the image in right directory? The alt tag in `img` is set as **graphic** so that was showing because image can't be found.

Comment: I tested with some external image. It's working fine. Check- http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/422x1Lmn/

Comment: sorry @aniskhan001 I have recheck it and yes that images are no on the directory. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **alt** tag in `img` is set as **graphic**. It will show only if those images can't be found.
Check the images if they are in right directory.

It's working in the **[FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/422x1Lmn/)**.